# Export menu problem in blender

Tags: import

When I want to import projects I click import button, then opens import menu, but when I press again for example folder to select in import menu then import menu changes in to export menu. Also when I just press for example 3d model cube in editor then export menu opens even thought I haven't pressed export button. Is it bug or I need just change things in settings?